# ASP.Net WEB application transferring to another computer

Tags: sql, grouping

I have one table as payment

```
ser. paymentdate amount
1.   12 mar 2007 5000
1.   14 mar 2007 5000
2.   6 dec 2007  4000
3.   2 mar 2008  6000
4.   5 nov 2008  2000
```

i want select data from table group by month 
e.g record of 2007

```
month    amount
mar      10000
dec      4000
```

i can get data date wise by this query but not month wise.

Comment: what is the type of your paymentdate, is it string or a datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(m, paymentdate) [Month], 
    SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM 
    Payment
WHERE
    YEAR(paymentdate)=2007
GROUP BY DATENAME(m, paymentdate), MONTH(paymentdate)
ORDER BY MONTH(paymentdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL LIKE clause is used to compare a value to similar values using wildcard operators. There are two wildcards used in conjunction with the LIKE operator:

```
The percent sign (%)
The underscore (_)
```

The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters. The underscore represents a single number or character. The symbols can be used in combinations.

```
WHERE SALARY LIKE '%200%'
```

Finds any values that have 200 in any position

So according to your condition, take some variable which contains the month you want to be selected and then put the statement something like,

```
WHERE SALARYDATE LIKE '%mar%'
```

or
some other options for you

```
WHERE SALARY LIKE '200%'    Finds any values that start with 200
WHERE SALARY LIKE '%200%'   Finds any values that have 200 in any position
WHERE SALARY LIKE '_00%'    Finds any values that have 00 in the second and third positions
WHERE SALARY LIKE '2_%_%'   Finds any values that start with 2 and are at least 3 characters in length
WHERE SALARY LIKE '%2'  Finds any values that end with 2
WHERE SALARY LIKE '_2%3'    Finds any values that have a 2 in the second position and end with a 3
WHERE SALARY LIKE '2___3'   Finds any values in a five-digit number that start with 2 and end with 3
```